# Getting PHP output inside Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

i know PHP is a server side script and js is a client side but i have an issue..

I needed to bypass the browser security when doing an ajax request to another domain and it was difficult for me to be honest i had no idea what i was doing so i turned to php.. wooohooo....

The issue is i can only use JS and CSS to run arbitrarily ontop of my tracking system!

I wanted to add a newsfeed.csv so i made this php code to get the csv and convert it and store it into the variable $json.

```
    <?php
$file="http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/js/newsroomcustomer.csv";
$csv= file_get_contents($file);
$checkit = utf8_encode($csv);
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $checkit));
$json = json_encode($array);
?>
```

Is there a way to do an ajax get to get the variables output? meaning the json format of my csv..

This way i can have my PHP script on my webserver and it will be able to grab any link on any domain..

Thanks guys :)

Comment: You only missed the one bit to output yout data ... `echo $json;`

Comment: this is common practice....you are using your server as proxy for ajax request. Don't forget to add some error handling

Comment: Yes i know that prints my output @charlietfl but how do i implement this with Jquery to call it once page has loaded?

Comment: make an ajax request to path on server that runs that code

Comment: but nothing runs that code... Its just a php file that i am calling once the page has fully loaded... @charlietfl this is what i have been using.. what did i do wrong.. `$.ajax({
       url: 'file.php',
       success: function(htmlcsv) {
          $("body").prepend(htmlcsv);
       }
    });`

Comment: did you add the `echo`? Also will have to parse array returned to html in your ajax caallback

Comment: Yes even when i use `echo $json;` when i call the file with ajax it returns the PHP function and not the value of $json

Comment: are you calling a server? Can't run php without it being on server

Comment: @charlietfl ... ahhhhhh damn that was dumb i added it as an attachment to a wikis page instead of adding it in my directory on my server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment of Julio said:

Use `echo` to print the contents of the generated JSON string. It's as easy as `echo $json`.

---

Once your PHP script outputs the correct JSON string, you can send an AJAX request to your script with the following code (assuming you're using jQuery, which will make your life easier):

```
$.get('script.php', function (data) {
   console.log('Data received: ', data);
});
```

Comment: Yes i know that will print my output but how can you implement the output of a `file.php` inside an ajax request? or any type or request

Comment: here's the issue i was having even with `echo $json;` when i use your script or even an ajax call it returns the contents of the PHP file.. not the json string.. it gives me the whole php function @hidde